# Locating the FreezePanes point on an Excel window/worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook that I want to programmatically set the active cell to the top left corner. in some cases, the windows have freezepane = true, and when that is the case, I want to set the active cell to the cell where the freeze is set.  But I can't see any way to get that cell reference.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `ActiveWindow.SplitRow` And `ActiveWindow.SplitColumn` to find if there are any panes which are frozen

See this

```
Sub test()
    Dim Rw As Long, Col As Long

    'change sheet as applicable
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    With ActiveWindow
        If .SplitRow = 0 And .SplitColumn = 0 Then
            'no panes are frozen
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
        Else
            Rw = .SplitRow + 1
            Col = .SplitColumn + 1
            'select top left cell below the freeze pane
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rw, Col).Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if FreezePanes is true and Split is false.  Will SplitRow and SplitColumn still have meaningful values that tell me where the FreezePanes anchor cell is?

Comment: @MickMoignard, the answer is yes, which you will see when you try it :). +1